# make: *** [pipeline_kafka.so] Error 1

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka

I'm using PipelineDB and want to use the [Kafka extension](https://github.com/pipelinedb/pipeline_kafka). But when i'm trying to build it i get this error:

```
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -O2 -fpic -shared -o pipeline_kafka.so pipeline_kafka.o -L/usr/lib/pipelinedb/lib -Wl,--as-needed  /usr/lib/librdkafka.a -lz -lpthread -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/lib/pipelinedb/lib/pipelinedb/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/Makefile.shlib:311: recipe for target 'pipeline_kafka.so' failed
make: *** [pipeline_kafka.so] Error 1
```

usually my approach of building it works.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

libssl is missing. this fixes the Problem:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```